# How many sequences of 11 ones and 7 zeroes without consecutive zeroes exist?

Tags: combinatorics

I've been looking for solutions to such a problem, but only found solutions for any amount of zeroes and ones (without consecutive zeroes).

How many such sequences exist?

Comment: Well, it's more or less a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  Put spaces before, after, and between the seven $0's$.  The between ones must have at least one $1$ so put one in each.  Now you have a standard problem.  Can you finish from here?

Comment: One way to add context to a "bare problem statement" is by working out some small examples.  If eleven ones and seven zeros is too hard, how about cutting the size of the problem roughly in half?  Often the process of working out an example will suggest methods to attack the general problem.  In any event it will give your Readers a clear idea of the extent to which you have digested the problem statement.  Other ways of adding context are also possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the eleven ones out first and leave a bit of space to either side of the ones.

$$\underbrace{~}_{a}1\underbrace{~}_{b}1\underbrace{~}_{c}1\underbrace{~}_{d}1\underbrace{~}_{e}1\underbrace{~}_{f}1\underbrace{~}_{g}1\underbrace{~}_{h}1\underbrace{~}_{i}1\underbrace{~}_{j}1\underbrace{~}_{k}1\underbrace{~}_{\ell}$$

Now, pick which seven of the spaces are used by zeroes and close all the remaining unused spaces.  Choose the spaces *simultaneously*.  To count this, use [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).  We have twelve spaces available (*11 + 1*) and we want to *choose* seven of them to be used by zeroes.

The answer then is $$\binom{12}{7}$$

By choosing in this fashion, either zero or one $0$ will be in each space and as a result no $0$ will be next to another $0$.

Answer (score 3):

Take such a sequence and stick a $1$ at the end. You have a sequence
of $12$ ones and $7$ zeroes with each zero followed by a $1$. So you have
seven subwords $01$. Replace each of those by a $2$. You then have a sequence
of $5$ ones and seven twos. There are $\binom{12}5$ of these.
You can reverse the process. So there are $\binom{12}5$ of your sort of sequence.